# How to parse the following strings

Tags: c++, c, lex

I'd like to parse

```
CLASSA classAvalue;
CLASSB classBvalue;
... ....
CLASSX classXvalue;
```

text from a file..

their order is unpredictable
ie;

```
CLASSX classXvalue;
CLASSY classYvalue;
....   ......
CLASSA classAvalue;
CLASSB classBvalue;
```

I'm have classes /structure of name A,B,C....X and i need to push the values to their respective values , **I want to keep it simple, no regular expressions are to used for parsing this text..**
**RUNTIME is crucial for me.. I have a file which has >300MB of data to be parsed,**

I came with an idea of tokenizing the string strtok() .. but before pushing tvalue I have to compare whats type of data I'm pushing.. this is taking some time..

Some how I want to optimize the way of pushing the data to their relevant classes.. even milli seconds matter , at the end I might end up saving couple of precious seconds of runtime..

Please do share your thoughts on this, I'll be thankful..

Comment: Are the value data types consistent and just going to specific class? Or Different? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Your description of the problem needs more detail.  If the tokens *can be expressed* as regular expressions (I'm not saying actually use the REs, but just asking if it's possible), then the fastest way to scan them will be to hand code a discrete finite automaton.  If you give the REs, I will show you how to do that.

As has been said, using the file system in the best possible way is just as important as a good scanning algorithm.  You didn't give your OS, so we can't help you with that.  In many OSs, memory mapping (for example in Linux, `mmap`) is fastest.

Answer (score 0):

What is involved in "push[ing] values to their respective values"? Perhaps you meant respective class or some sort of accumulator variable/function? If you could provide an example of at least two different classes of data being processed that would go a long way towards getting the "best" answer.

For now I will assume that the data is presented exactly as shown in your question. Depending on how you are specifying your classes in the text file there are better ways to switch() on the value such as using an integer to avoid the strcmp() used below.

//pseudocode

```
while(not EOF)
  read a line from the file with fscanf or similar
  split sequence on first occurrence of a space
  switch() on the first segment which should be CLASS_
  call appropriate function to handle your data
```

//example Data:
myclassA 12345
myclassB 67890
myclassC 19348

```
int data
char class_str[MAX_CHARS];

ret = fscanf(fp,"%s %i",class_str,&data);
while(ret != EOF){
    switch(class_str){

        case(strcmp(class_Str,"myclassA")==0):
            myclassA_data_processing_function();
            break;

        case(strcmp(class_Str,"myclassB")==0):
            myclassB_data_processing_function();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If single milliseconds matters - then try to implement [Trie data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to have fastest type matching. Assuming you read type already to `char type[]` and you know `type` length:

```
switch (typeLength) {
case 3: // for cases where only one type aplies like e.g. Abc 
  if (0 == memcmp(type, "Abc", 3) { /*  read Abc object from stream */ }
  else ERROR;
  break;
case 5: // e.g. "Abcde", "Abcdf", "Ebcde"
  switch (type[0]) {
     case 'A': 
         // "A,,,"
         switch (type[1]) {
             case 'b':
...
                 switch (type[4]) {
                    case 'e': // read Abcde object
                    case 'f': // read Abcdf object
...     default: ERROR
     case 'E': // only Ebcde matches
         if (0 == memcmp(type + 1, "bcde") { /*  read Ebcde object from stream */ }
         else ERROR;
.....
```

This is not very easy to implement - but I believe it is the fastest way to determine object type from string if only you know the types before parsing.

Answer (score 0):

In simple cases like yours, IO performance is often more important than CPU performance. So you should make sure that you get the buffering right, for example.